# How to load XML document in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Please check my code.

**questions.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("questions");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

$week = date("W");
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".QUIZ_QUESTION." WHERE week='".$week."'";  
$result = mysql_query($query);

header("Content-type:  application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  $node = $dom->createElement("question");  
  $question = $parnode->appendChild($node); 
  $ansAtrribute = $question->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);

  $que = $dom->createElement("que",$row['question']);
  $quenode = $question->appendChild($que);

  $qryOpt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".QUIZ_OPTION." WHERE question_id='".$row['id']."'");
  while($gerOptions = mysql_fetch_array($qryOpt)){
  $ans = $dom->createElement("ans",$gerOptions['option']);
  $ansNode = $question->appendChild($ans);
  $ansAtrribute = $ansNode->setAttribute("ans",$gerOptions['is_correct']);
  }
} 
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

I am directly run the `questions.php` here is the XML output:

**Output:**

```
-<questions>
  -<question id="1">
    <que>What is PHP?</que>
    <ans ans="0">Fruit</ans>
    <ans ans="1">Language</ans>
    <ans ans="0">Game</ans>
  </question>
</questions>
```

**quiz.php**

```
<?php
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $xmlDoc->load("questions.php");

    $questions = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("question");
    $question= $questions->item($qnum)->getElementsByTagName("que")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $ans1= $questions->item($qnum)->getElementsByTagName("ans")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $ans1r= $questions->item($qnum)->getElementsByTagName("ans")->item(0)->getAttribute('ans');
    $ans2= $questions->item($qnum)->getElementsByTagName("ans")->item(1)->nodeValue;
    $ans2r= $questions->item($qnum)->getElementsByTagName("ans")->item(1)->getAttribute('ans');
    $ans3= $questions->item($qnum)->getElementsByTagName("ans")->item(2)->nodeValue;
    $ans3r= $questions->item($qnum)->getElementsByTagName("ans")->item(2)->getAttribute('ans');
?>
```

I am running the `quiz.php` but the `questions.php` doesn't load.

I am getting following error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in file:///G:/xampp/htdocs/txtweb/quiz/questions.php, line: 30 in G:\xampp\htdocs\txtweb\quiz\quiz.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in G:\xampp\htdocs\txtweb\quiz\quiz.php on line 6

I am posting my complete code. Please let me know where is error of my code?

Comment: I actually have not much idea about PHP, but I would guess that `load(question.php") doesn't load the response given by the web server, but instead loads the actual source file `questions.php`, hence you have no starting `<`

Comment: @dirkk `question.php` is showing the xml format. Please check my output

Comment: Yes, if you are running it via the web server, i.e. access it through your browser. But the file itself is a PHP source file as you have shown in your question.

Comment: @dirkk yes you are right. I have tested if i write static content `questions.xml` instead of `questions.php` i am getting the correct output. But how can i use it in with `php` extension. This is dynamic content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By executing

```
$xmlDoc->load("questions.php");
```

you do load the PHP source file itself, not the rendered output. Your web server is responsible to interpret and execute a PHP file and then compute the result (which in this case will be the resulting XML file).

Sou to get the XML file you will have to use a HTTP request, something like

```
$xmlDoc->load("http://YOURURL/questions.php");
```

should work. Of course you will have to replace `YOURURL` with your actual URL and path to the script.

Answer (score 0):

use `libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);` in top of php file i.e. quiz.php like this

```
<?php
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("questions.php");
```

this removes unnecesary internal warnings.

and update your xml file with this-

```
    <rdf:RDF>
    -<questions>
      -<question id="1">
        <que>What is PHP?</que>
        <ans ans="0">Fruit</ans>
        <ans ans="1">Language</ans>
        <ans ans="0">Game</ans>
      </question>
    </questions>
  </rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: So you get an error and your reaction is to simply suppress the error message? Wow, that is _terrible_ advice. Error messages usually have a reason and a programmer should consider them.